# How to interacting with existing ERC-20 token on testnet?

Tags: contract-development, tokens, erc-20, testnets, testing

I'd like to interact with ERC-20 tokens transactions on testnet (preferably ropsten).

1. Are there any ERC-20 tokens faucets?
2. Is it common that token issuers deploy their contracts on testnet?
3. What are my options to test known ERC-20 transactions on testnet?

Answer (score 1):

While developing, I prefer using [ganache-cli](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli) (formerly known as testrpc).

It starts a rpc node to which you can connect and issue commands.

It has several advantages over testnet:

- No need to wait for the testnet to sync. It works once you start it.
- It runs locally (it doesn't consume your bandwidth).
- It gives you a list of accounts with 100 ETH in them when it starts.
- It mines transactions automatically, in an instant (you can tell it to mine them only after some seconds if you want though).

Comment: actually I would like to test-interact with contracts from major erc-20 tokens because I am building a wallet and need to see what kind of logs the transactions produce and what transaction data I get.

Answer (score 1):

As per the first answer, ganache is really the best starting point for testing. 
When you do want to deploy a test to Rinkeby or Ropsten these are 2 available faucets.
Rinkeby: http://faucet.rinkeby.io
Ropsten: http://faucet.metamask.io
You'll need MetaMask enable to use the Ropsten faucet.

Comment: actually I would like to test-interact with contracts from major erc-20 tokens because I am building a wallet and need to see what kind of logs the transactions produce and what transaction data I get.

Answer (score 0):

For many of the contracts you are interested to work with, they were deployed before ERC-155.

You can just replay the signed transactions from mainnet onto testnet. :-p

Answer (score 0):

For testing specific ERC20 coin:

1. you can deploy the same contract yourself and play with it.
2. Use one of the decentralized exchange as Kyber to swap ETH to one of these tokens - they have a Ropsten DEX so you can swap from testEth to test other ERC20 - [Kyber Ropsten](https://developer.kyber.network/docs/Environments-Ropsten/)